# Convert PDF to TIFF Format

Tags: vb.net, pdf, tiff

I am writting a VB.Net application. I need to be able to convert either a Word or PDF file to TIF format.

Free would be nice but I will also accept low cost.

I would like sample code if possible, VB is preferable but I also know c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many products I found that can do this. Some have a cost while some are free.

I used Black Ice http://www.blackice.com/Printer%20Drivers/Tiff%20Printer%20Drivers.htm. This is afordable at about $40. I didn't buy this one though.

I ended up using a free one called MyMorph.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with imagemagick (you do have to download ghostscript, too.).  You just need to use VB to run it as a process.

```
Dim imgmgk As New Process()

    With imgmgk.StartInfo
        .FileName = v_locationOfImageMagickConvert.exe
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .RedirectStandardInput = False
        .Arguments = " -units PixelsPerInch " & v_pdf_filename & " -depth 16 -flatten +matte –monochrome –density 288 -compress ZIP " & v_tiff_filename

    End With

    imgmgk.Start()

    Dim output As String = imgmgk.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
    Dim errorMsg As String = imgmgk.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
    imgmgk.WaitForExit()
    imgmgk.Close()
```

The arguments are varied - use imagemagick docs to see what they are.  You can do something as simple as just pass the pdf file name and the tiff file name for a simple conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Atalasoft DotImage (commerial product - obligatory disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft and write a lot of the PDF code):

```
// this code extracts images from the PDF - there may be multiple images per page
public void PdfToTiff(Stream pdf, Stream tiff)
{
    TiffEncoder encoder = new TiffEncoder(tiff);

    PdfImageSource images = new PdfImageSource(pdf);

    encoder.Save(tiff, images, null);
}

// this code renders each page
public void PdfToTiff(string pathToPdf, Stream tiff)
{
    TiffEncoder encoder = new TiffEncoder(tiff);

    FileSystemImageSource images = new FileSystemImageSource(pathToPdf, true);

    encoder.Save(tiff, images, null);
}
```

The latter example is probably what you want.  It works on a path because FileSystemImageSource takes advantage of code to operate on the file system with wildcards.  It's overkill for the task, really.  If you wanted to do it without you would have this:

```
public void PdfToTiff(Stream pdf, Stream tiff)
{
    TiffEncoder encoder = new TiffEncoder();
    encoder.Append = true;

    PdfDecoder decoder = new PdfDecoder();
    int pageCount = decoder.GetFrameCount(pdf);
    for (int i=0; i < pageCount; i++) {
        using (AtalaImage image = decoder.Read(pdf, i, null)) {
            encoder.Save(tiff, image, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Aspose.Pdf dotnet package. Here is a sample code:

```cs
public byte[] ConvertPdfToTiff(byte[] sourcePdfDoc)
{
    var license = new Aspose.Pdf.License();
    license.SetLicense("Aspose.Pdf.lic");

    // Load PDF with an instance of Document                        
    var document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(new MemoryStream(sourcePdfDoc));

    // Create an object of tiffDevice
    var renderer = new Aspose.Pdf.Devices.TiffDevice();

    // Convert a particular page and save the image in TIFF format
    using (var m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        renderer.Process(document, m);
        m.Position = 0;
        return m.ToArray();
    }
}
```